# Text not aligning middle

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see the text is aligned towards the top instead of in the middle.

It occurs on chrome as well as firefox, various versions including latest.

Various Line-height / Font-size / Vertical-align doesnt fix anything, it always stays slightly upwards. I can't find a solution to what this causes?
There is really no fancy css added to it, this is just a blank h1 with padding to it.

Comment: Regardless, please show the code that produced your unexpected output.

Comment: I found the solution. It is my Helvetica. (standard macbook pro)

If I use arial it aligns nicely in the middle, if i use helvetica it is slightly tilted upwards.

see what i mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/fgUf5/

Comment: The font doesn't look aligned to the top if you take the , comma into account.

Comment: Looks fine to me - the vertical alignment leaves space for descenders on letters such as y and g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is my Helvetica. (standard macbook pro font)

If I use arial it aligns nicely in the middle, if i use helvetica it is slightly (1px-ish) tilted upwards/downwards.

see what i mean here: jsfiddle.net/fgUf5

Answer (score 0):

I think you either have a padding or margin issue. Check to see if you are calling and what happens when you taken them off.